# Report expected value or other measure of centrality from Weibull model?

Tags: r, survival, weibull-distribution

I went through a tutorial on survival analysis and learned to compute the median from a weibull:

```
wb <- survreg(Surv(interval, censored) ~ 1, data = .x, dist = 'weibull')
 wb
Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(interval, censored) ~ 1, data = pdata)

Coefficients:
(Intercept) 
   1.692154 

Scale= 0.8255916 

Loglik(model)= -220389.6   Loglik(intercept only)= -220389.6
n= 99261
```

I can compute the median with:

```
predict(wb, type = "quantile", p = 0.5, newdata = data.frame(1))
       1 
4.013099
```

Is this the convention? If the context is churn in marketing or product analytics and the time unit used was months, could I say that the expected lifetime of a new subscription is ~4 months?

I was reading this post: [Attempting to find mean of Weibull function in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/361191/attempting-to-find-mean-of-weibull-function-in-r)

In that post, the OP asks about calculating expected value.The accepted answer refers to a formula that use shape and scale, but my `wb` variable has only a Scale parameter, not a shape one.

Can I compute expected value in a similar manner? How? What's the convention? Just the median? How can I report expected months duration of a new customer or subscription using my wb weibull model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great question because you ask about "convention" and not right/wrong. So first of all with respect to convention there's usually two ways of composing a survival time from a survival distribution: mean and median. The problem with the median route is that very often a survival probability prediction never actually goes below 0.5, so median is misleading (though a similar but different problem exists for mean). In your example median makes sense as it's a continuous parametric distribution.

Note that mathematically the expected lifetime is not the median, it's the mean. So be careful how you report that. The median is usually reported as it's a quantity that clinicians (for example) can understand: e.g. "50% of people with the same profile should die by this time".

Now about calculating the mean from your distribution. `survreg` uses the slightly confusing framework introduced by "The statistical analysis of failure time data" (Kalbfleisch, Prentice). This means that you have to know the conversion from the `survreg` output to the 'standard' representation for each of the possible distributions, and they don't tell you in the documentation, which is very annoying. An R package I maintain does the hard work for you but it's overly-complicated for this example. However copying the relevant parts from the package:

Below is a table with the distribution from `survreg` and the corresponding parameters in a standard parametrisation. For the below, `scale = wb$scale` and `location = as.numeric(wb$coefficients[1])`.

| Distribution | Parameters |
| --- | --- |
| Weibull(shape, scale) | Shape = 1/scale. Scale = exp(location) |
| Exponential(scale) | Scale = exp(location) |
| Lognormal(logmean,logsd) | Logmean = location, Logsd = scale |
| Loglogistic(scale,shape) | Scale = exp(location), Shape = 1/scale |

Now you can just substitute these parameters to get the results you want (e.g. look on wikipedia for analytical formulas, or even use one of my packages {distr6})

Edit: Just want to add some clarity to this answer. Substituting the above table into a distribution will give you the expectation of the *baseline distribution* not a predicted distribution for an individual. This should work in your case as you fit a model with no covariates but not in general.

Edit2: Reproducible example:

````
library(survival)
fit = survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = rats)
scale = fit$scale
location = as.numeric(fit$coefficients[1])

shape = 1/scale
scale = exp(location)

scale * gamma(1 + 1/shape)
# (yes plugging my own package here but just to demonstrate result is same!)
distr6::Weibull$new(shape = shape, scale = scale)$mean()
```
````

Comment: This is great, thank you! May I ask, while playing around yesterday I tried `predict(wb, newdata=data.frame(1))` which returned 8.096338 . I noticed this is also the same as `exp(intercept)`, `exp(2.091412)`. Is 8.09 the 'expected' value? How can I interpret that?

Comment: Meh, actually the example I gave in my comment refers to a different WB model and I currently cannot recreate the one I had when I posted. Nevertheless, it seems to hold that when predicting with `newdata= data.frame(1)` I get the exp() of the intercept returned...

Comment: So. Firstly `exp(intercept)` is not the expected value and the expected value will depend on the distribution you choose. In general `exp(intercept)` relates to the scale parameter, which means that if your Weibull has a shape of 1, then it is equivalent to Exponential in which case the expected value is `exp(intercept)`, but only in that specific case.

Comment: Just for absolute clarity, here's what I did and what I got: `scale <- wb$scale` (0.8427523), `location <- as.numeric(wb$coefficients[1])` (2.091412), `Shape <- 1/scale` (1.186588) and then copying the expected value of a Weibul model from the linked post: `Scale*gamma(1+(1/Shape))` which returned 7.638329. Is my expected value of the baseline distribution 7.638329?

Comment: I've added a reprex to my answer, which will be easier to read than in the comments

Comment: Thank you very much! Feeling better about this now